# Visual Studio 2022 C# Automated Compiler Constants do not work in Published builds - can this be enabled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish

I recently noticed in my project that the name of the project configuration was being injected into the compiler definitions automatically, e.g. a project configuration of "MySpecialBuild" could be using in source code with #if MYSPECIALBUILD.

I have taken out all of my manual defines in preference to this neat feature, but upon making a publish profile for testing, I have found that the Publish mode does not inject these definitions. I find it odd that the publish build process works differently to the IDE build process - is there a setting that enables this feature in publish mode? Perhaps something in the .pubxml file?

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just about to delete this, because I've been a bit of a fool, but since it got 2 upvotes already I thought that I'd explain what went wrong.

Effectively my development build settings are "MySpecialBuild - AnyCPU", but my Publish profile was set to build "MySpecialBuild - x64". The project itself in the x64 build configuration was set to "Debug" even though the solution was set to "MySpecialBuild".

There are two alternate solutons to this:

1. Fix the build profiles for all target platforms.
   -or-
2. Publish using the same profile that you're building in the IDE.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people